# How to use type Date in new Java Object?

Tags: java

I would like to know how to use type Date in new object?

I'll explain a bit more be showing my code:

I got a Java class called:

Reiziger:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Reiziger {
    private String naam;
    private Date gbdatum;

    public Reiziger(String nm, Date gbdtm) {
        this.naam = nm;
        this. gbdatum = gbdtm;
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

    public void setNaam(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
    }

    public Date getGBdatum() {
        return gbdatum;
    }

    public void setGBdatum(Date gbdatum) {
        this.gbdatum = gbdatum;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return naam + gbdatum;
    }
}
```

And a Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reiziger r1 = new Reiziger("Joost", "01-01-1994");
        Reiziger r2 = new Reiziger("Hans", null);

        ReizigerOracleDaoImpl i1 = new ReizigerOracleDaoImpl();
        i1.alleReizigers.add(r1);
        i1.alleReizigers.add(r2);
        System.out.println(i1.alleReizigers);
    }
}
```

As you see in my main i tried alot of things only null is working. I want to add the the object a date -> for example: 01-01-1994 but doesnt work.

I tried it without the " " also nothing.

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You actually have to pass in a Date, not a string. Java won't implicitly convert it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are passing a `String` object to your constructor, but then attempting to assign it to a member variable of a different type (`Date`). No can do. Square peg, round hole. You must first parse that text into an object of the correct type.

Another problem: You are using terrible old date-time class `Date` where you should be using the modern `java.time.LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate.of( 1994 , Month.JANUARY , 1 )
```

## java.time

> I would like to know how to use type Date in new object?

**Don’t.**

Apparently you want a date-only value, so use a date-only class rather than a date-plus-time-of-day class.

Furthermore, **never use `java.util.Date`**. It is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Specify the month part either by number 1-12 for January-December or by the `Month` enum class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1994 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ;
```

Change your member variable:

```
private Date gbdatum ;
```

…to:

```
private LocalDate gbdatum ;
```

Change your constructor to:

```
public Reiziger(String nm, LocalDate gbdtm)
```

Call it like this:

```
Reiziger r1 = new Reiziger( 
    "Joost" , 
    LocalDate.of( 1994 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) 
) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: thank you very much i appreciate the time you spend to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is defined as taking in a `Date` object, however you are trying to pass in a String. Java does not automatically convert the String to a Date.

What you need to do is use a **DateFormatter**.

This uses a defined Date pattern to convert your incoming String into the Date object you want to use.

In your case, you would want to do something similar to this:

```
String dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy";

try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Date dateToUse = df.parse("01-01-1994");

    // Or this way
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("01-01-1994", formatter);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    // Do something
}
```

Here are the links to the Java PI:
SimpleDateFormatter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

DateTimeFormatter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

LocalDate: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: I made the format follow "MM-dd-yyyy" since countries outside of the US follow this format. Obviously if I have the day/month switched, just change them in there.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

`Date(String)` is Deprecated. Use `Date(Long)` 
After that use a SimpleDateFormatter `new SimpleDateFormatter ("dd-MM-yyyy") ;`

Comment: And how is OP supposed to obtain a `long`-representation for the `Date` in `String`-representation?

Comment: ´String stDate = "17-09-1997"; stDate = stDate.replace("-", ""); Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(stDate));´

Comment: You know what a Unix timestamp is?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

Comment: You should [edit] your answer, so it reflects a correct and complete solution... (btw I did not downvote).

Answer (score 0):

`"01-01-1994"` creates a `String` with those contents. To create a `Date` you will need to use one of it's constructors. For example, using the default constructor

```
Reiziger r1 = new Reiziger("Joost", new Date());
```

will work.

For more information on the class along with it's other constructors see [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse-java.lang.String-).

However the `Date` class is a bit old at this point, and as you see from other answers it's a bit of a mess to work with properly, instead I would recommend using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) from the `java.time` package. If you are using that class then the following will create a date representing `"01-01-1994"`: `LocalDate.of(1994, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend using classes from the more recent `java.time` library but if you want to use `java.util.Date` and its subclasses and set the date via a `String` then you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
private final static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
 // ...
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // do exception handling for `parse`
    Reiziger r1 = new Reiziger("Joost", dateFormat.parse("01-01-1994"));
    Reiziger r2 = new Reiziger("Hans", null);
    // ...
}
```